# TypeError while running deploy.py script in brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I initialized a new brownie project via the terminal by

`$ brownie init`

I wrote the following script in python:

```
def simple_print():
    print("Hello World!")

def main():
    simple_print()
```

saved it as deploy.py in the srcipts folder and then ran the following command in the terminal:

`$ brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

and got the following error:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true --server.port 8545 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --wallet.mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Users\kashy\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\kashy\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "C:\Users\kashy\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "C:\Users\kashy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 122, in import_module
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.Works..CS.Web3.brownie_simple_storage.scripts.deploy'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Been at this for 4 days now, cannot find a solution. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the port numbers are the same between GUI and CLI. I was able to fix by going into Ganache (GUI) settings -> server and reset the port to `8545`. Save and restart. Brownie should attach next time you run your deploy script.